# How get the text out of the element using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple element that looks like that:

```
[<div class=​"cls-ab-healthAppsTitle">Application Title</div>​]
```

To get it I use below Javascript command typid in the Chrome console directly:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('cls-ab-healthAppsTitle')
```

What I want is to get just the `Application Title` text from it. How's that possible using Javascript?

I have tried a couple of options already but all returned `unidentified`. This is what I tried:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('cls-ab-healthAppsTitle').innerHTML;
document.getElementsByClassName('cls-ab-healthAppsTitle').innerText;
document.getElementsByClassName('cls-ab-healthAppsTitle').textContent;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anytime you see a method with an **s**, as in `getElements..`, as in plural, it returns a [**nodeList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not a single element, even if there is only one matching element, hence the `elements` part, and not just `element`, there's a possibility there could be more than one element.

To get an element from the nodeList, you can access it like an array

```
document.getElementsByClassName('cls-ab-healthAppsTitle')[0].textContent;
```

Most of the time you'd be better off with `querySelector`, which is also supported in IE8 (`getElementsByClassName` is not).

```
document.querySelector('.cls-ab-healthAppsTitle').textContent;
```

`querySelector` gets the first matching element, if you need a nodeList you can use `querySelectorAll`to get all the elements matching the selector.

Comment: Awesome! Spot on! Thanks for the answer and the additional information!

Comment: So do you recommend using `querySelector` for most cases? Instead of using the `getElementsBy<X>` methods?

Comment: Yes, both `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are easier to use, and they accept regular CSS selectors so they work almost like jQuery out of the box, and they work in IE8, wich `getElementsByClassName` does not.

Comment: Thanks again. Last question is why is there a dot before this class name? -> `.cls-ab-healthAppsTitle`

Comment: Because it's a CSS selector, `querySelector` accepts CSS selectors, so it can be used for tagname, ID's, classes, and even attributes and children etc. It accepts almost the same stuff as jQuery does.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the document.getElementsByClassName ('cls-ab-healthAppsTitle').textContent equal to a variable so have something to work with?

```
var text = document.getElementsByClassName('cls-ab-healthAppsTitle').textContent;
```

Hopefully this helps?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent

Answer (score -1):

Try with JQuery:

```
$('.cls-ab-healthAppsTitle').html() or $('.cls-ab-healthAppsTitle').text()
```